# fgetcsv is eating the first letter of a String if it's an Umlaut

Tags: php, xml, csv, character-encoding, diacritics

I am importing contents from an Excel-generated CSV-file into an XML document like:

```
$csv = fopen($csvfile, r);
$words = array();

while (($pair = fgetcsv($csv)) !== FALSE) {
    array_push($words, array('en' => $pair[0], 'de' => $pair[1]));
}
```

The inserted data are English/German expressions.

I insert these values into an XML structure and output the XML as following:

```
$dictionary = new SimpleXMLElement('<dictionary></dictionary>');
//do things
$dom = dom_import_simplexml($dictionary) -> ownerDocument;
$dom -> formatOutput = true;

header('Content-encoding: utf-8'); //<3 UTF-8
header('Content-type: text/xml'); //Headers set to correct mime-type for XML output!!!!

echo $dom -> saveXML();
```

This is working fine, yet I am encountering one really strange problem. When the first letter of a String is an Umlaut (like in `Österreich` or `Ägypten`) the character will be omitted, resulting in `gypten` or `sterreich`. If the Umlaut is in the middle of the String (`Russische Föderation`) it gets transferred correctly. Same goes for things like `ß` or `é` or whatever.

All files are UTF-8 encoded and served in UTF-8.

This seems rather strange and bug-like to me, yet maybe I am missing something, there's a lot of smart people around here.

Comment: Is ucfirst() being used at all? I seem to recall issues with characters with diacritic marks, and having to use mb_convert_case() on the first character instead.

Comment: @jornak The values are "correctly capitalized" in the CSV file so I didn't think I'll have to mess with that, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: Why don't you start those words with a prefix?
Then remove it after adding those words.

Comment: @m90 check this out,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571626/simplyxml-and-accented-characters-in-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so this seems to be a bug in `fgetcsv`.

I am now processing the CSV data on my own (a little cumbersome), but it is working and I do not have any encoding issues at all.

This is (a not-yet-optimized version of) what I am doing:

```
$rawCSV = file_get_contents($csvfile);

$lines = preg_split ('/$\R?^/m', $rawCSV); //split on line breaks in all operating systems: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7498886/797194

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    array_push($words, getCSVValues($line));
}
```

The `getCSVValues` is coming from **[here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.split.php#81490)** and is needed to deal with CSV lines like this (commas!):

```
"I'm a string, what should I do when I need commas?",Howdy there
```

It looks like:

```
function getCSVValues($string, $separator=","){

    $elements = explode($separator, $string);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($elements); $i++) {
        $nquotes = substr_count($elements[$i], '"');
        if ($nquotes %2 == 1) {
            for ($j = $i+1; $j < count($elements); $j++) {
                if (substr_count($elements[$j], '"') %2 == 1) { // Look for an odd-number of quotes
                    // Put the quoted string's pieces back together again
                    array_splice($elements, $i, $j-$i+1,
                        implode($separator, array_slice($elements, $i, $j-$i+1)));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if ($nquotes > 0) {
            // Remove first and last quotes, then merge pairs of quotes
            $qstr =& $elements[$i];
            $qstr = substr_replace($qstr, '', strpos($qstr, '"'), 1);
            $qstr = substr_replace($qstr, '', strrpos($qstr, '"'), 1);
            $qstr = str_replace('""', '"', $qstr);
        }
    }
    return $elements;

}
```

Quite a bit of a workaround, but it seems to work fine.

**EDIT:**

There's a also a **[filed bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55507)** for this, apparently this depends on the locale settings.

Comment: if it is a bug in a PHP function, you should probably report it on php.net. However, this may also help you: http://static.zend.com/topics/multibyte-fgetcsv.pdf

Comment: I can confirm it probably is a bug in PHP as I tried any sensible method of debugging:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653369/str-getcsv-is-broken-clips-diacritics

Comment: @JosefSábl I encountered this quite a few times by now and found that setting the correct locale setting via `setlocale(LC_ALL,'de_DE.UTF-8')` (german in my case) seems to "patch" that quite fine.

Answer (score 3):

If the string comes from Excel (I had problems with the letter ø disappearing if it was in the beginning of the string) ... then this fixed it:

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.ISO-8859-1');

Comment: It all seems to be a locale issue: http://static.zend.com/topics/multibyte-fgetcsv.pdf

Comment: Had same issue when importing from .csv file which is generated from .xlsx. setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.ISO-8859-1'); fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

If other umlauts in the middle appear ok, then this is not a base encoding issue. The fact that it happens at the beginning of the line probably indicates some incompatibility with the newline mark. Perhaps the CSV was generated with a different newline encoding.

This happens when moving files between different OS:

- Windows: `\r\n` (characters 13 and 10)
- Linux: `\n` (character 10)
- Mac OS: `\r` (character 13)

If I were you, I would verify the newline mark to be sure.

If in Linux: `hexdump -C filename | more` and inspect the document.

You can change the newline marks with a `sed` expression if that's the case.

Hope that helped!

Comment: This sounds pretty reasonable, but unfortunately the german (umlaut-hell) expressions are not on the beginning of a new line, but in the middle. I just identified `fgetcsv` as the culprit as the content gets transferred quite fine when you just use sth like `file_get_contents`.

Comment: Ok, so now I am manually processing the file's contents and it is working just fine. I'll write an answer myself. Thanks for your input!!

Answer (score 2):

A bit simpler workaround (but pretty dirty):

```
//1. replace delimiter in input string with delimiter + some constant
$dataLine = str_replace($this->fieldDelimiter, $this->fieldDelimiter . $this->bugFixer, $dataLine);

//2. parse
$parsedLine = str_getcsv($dataLine, $this->fieldDelimiter);

//3. remove the constant from resulting strings.
foreach ($parsedLine as $i => $parsedField)
{
    $parsedLine[$i] = str_replace($this->bugFixer, '', $parsedField);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be some sort of `utf8_encode()` problem. [This comment](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php#103126) on the documentation page seems to indicate if you encode an Umlaut when it's already encoded, it could cause issues.

Maybe test to see if the data is already utf-8 encoded with [`mb_detect_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php).

Comment: I never do/did any encoding on the values. The problem was a bug in `fgetcsv`, see my answer for a workaround.